# Unusual entry in Google web & app activity

Tags: samsung, security, google

On my google web & app activity I noticed an unusual entry. Should I be concerned? It says:

Used: qualcomm.qti.services.secureui.com

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry but your question is quite short. Please extend it and add details about your phone (model and Android version). Also a screenshot of the "unusual entry" would be good.